# Python interactive works, script doesn't (mac)

Tags: python, macos, pyserial

Just starting out with Python.
This script works fine in the interactive python, but doesn't seem to execute as a stand alone script.  No errors, seems happy.  (I guess the prob could be on other end.  Its a PIC micro controller attached via an xbee-2 used as a modem.  But somehow I feel not since it works via interactive and also via xbee app.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART', 2400, timeout=1)
ser.write("1Hg")
ser.write("1Hg")
ser.write("1Hg")
ser.close()
```

Mac 10.9.5, python 2.7.10, and pyserial 2.7
tia

Comment: What's the expected outcome and what's actually happening?

Comment: If you're on Mac 10.9.5, then `/usr/bin/python2.7` is not Python 2.7.10, it's 2.7.2 or 2.7.3. So you've got two separate Python 2.7 installations, the one Apple gave you and another one you installed somewhere else, and you're presumably using one in the interactive terminal and the other one in your script.

Comment: OK, abarnert, you got me on a trail! thanks.  Yup seeing different versions.  Will check back in.  Once again, thanks!

Comment: Ok, both interactive & script report same version.  Will be back after digging up  a serial null modem adapter and more testing.. (python is writing, CoolTerm is reading)  Thanks guys!